# How to locate or write Xpath for an element of an Hybrid app which has only class and no other attribute

Tags: cordova, selenium-webdriver, appium, android-uiautomator

I am new to mobile automation and Appium and unable to find a way to get xpath or locate an element, getting following node details in `uiautomatorviewer`:

```
index:0  
text:  
resourceid:  
class: android.view.View  
package: com.divami.balfour
```

[Node Details and Tree structure in uiautomator](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw83c9ANLZxea2s0QVE3TE5sRWM&authuser=0)

Node tree structure and Node details image for element text field

Comment: By class name. Please see this [link](https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: @Eugene I tried by ClassName but there are other nodes also present having same class. And also tried to get all elements by that class name through FindElemets in list but as the node changes elements belong to other parent. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: In this case we need  more details. Could you please share the apk or/and full tree of the elements?

Comment: @Eugene, I have added the link of an image of Node Details and tree sturcture,as I am unable to add image in stackoverflow edit box for now.

Comment: The site asked permissions. You can provide the link on the image,

Comment: I have given the permissions now, Stackoverflow not allowing me to attach image here, it is asking for at least 10 pts to attach.

Comment: I suggest to use the [appium inspector tool](https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-exe#inspector--recorder) that will help you find xpath of the element.

Comment: I have tried that too, it's showing the same as in uiautomator for windows

Comment: Yes the structure the same but the appium tool allows to determinate the xpath to the object. Do you want send me the apk?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that as my company doesn't allow me can you tell me the steps to get Xpath from Appium tool. I have tried that but not getting Xpath in 'node details' section.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it by class name and index:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.view.View' and @index='0']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your picture the xpath has to be something like that

```
//android.widget.FrameLayout[0]/android.webkit.WebView[0]/android.widget.View[0]/android.widget.View[2]/android.widget.EditText[1]
```

I am not sure that I created that correct but I hope you understand the idea.
If this still doesn't work,
please get the page source from the application (xml format). Then copy the source to a [xpath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) web service.

Comment: I get the page source from app, its not giving me complete source covering all element. Please find the [Page Source](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8421fda024a3228ff8186e6dcd50392a) in xml.

Comment: This app is based on Cordova developed in html and js, is there any way to locate in it as I only can reach upto WebView.